# EF Core - Migrate from Table Per Type to Table Per Hierarchy

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm trying to migrate from using TPT (a table per subclass) to TPH (One table for all subclasses).

This is my starting point for TPT:

entities:

```cs
[Serializable]
public abstract class VeganItem<TVeganItemEstablishment> : DomainEntity<int>
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int IsNotVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public int IsVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public int RatingsCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<Option> Tags { get; set; }

    [PropertyName("veganItemEstablishments", Ignore = true)]
    public virtual ICollection<TVeganItemEstablishment> VeganItemEstablishments { get; set; }
}


[ElasticsearchType(RelationName = "groceryitem", IdProperty = "Id")]
public class GroceryItem : VeganItem<GroceryItemEstablishment>
{
}

[ElasticsearchType(RelationName = "menuitem", IdProperty = "Id")]
public class MenuItem : VeganItem<MenuItemEstablishment>
{
}
```

OnModelCreating:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<GroceryItem>(gi =>
{
    gi.HasIndex(e => new { e.CompanyName, e.Name }).IsUnique();
    gi.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
    gi.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
    gi.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    gi.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
    gi.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
    gi.Property(e => e.Tags)
        .HasConversion(
            v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
            v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Option>>(v, null),
            new ValueComparer<IList<Option>>(
                (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
                c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
                c => (IList<Option>)c.ToList()));
});

modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItem>(mi =>
{
    mi.HasIndex(e => new { e.CompanyName, e.Name }).IsUnique();
    mi.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
    mi.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
    mi.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    mi.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
    mi.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
    mi.Property(e => e.Tags)
    .HasConversion(
        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Option>>(v, null),
        new ValueComparer<IList<Option>>(
            (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
            c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
            c => (IList<Option>)c.ToList()));
});

public DbSet<GroceryItem> GroceryItems { get; set; }
public DbSet<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
```

So I want just one table called `VeganItems`. What is it that is actually causing there to be 2 tables - `GroceryItems` and `MenuItems`? As I have tried a couple of things and they didn't work. EF Core uses TPH by default so I'm unsure why it is using TPT. I'm wondering if it is because my base entity is a generic type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EF Core uses TPH by default so I'm unsure why it is using TPT. I'm wondering if it is because my base entity is a generic type.

Generic type is one of the problems. The other is that it is *not* a base *entity*, but just base *class*. In order to be considered entity, there must be either `DbSet<T>`, or `ModelBuilder.Entity<T>()` call, or applied `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>`, or some discorevered entity navigation property (either collection or reference) referring to it - see [Including types in the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#including-types-in-the-model).

You don't have any of these, so the model is not even TPT (common table containing common properties + single table per each derived entity containing specific properties), but some sort of a TPC (Table-Per-Class, not currently supported by EF Core), where there is no common table - all the data is in concrete tables for each derived entity.

So, in order to use TPT you need to fix both issues. Generic class cannot be used as entity type because its type is not enough to identify it (each generic instantiation is different type, `typeof(Foo<Bar>) != typeof(Foo<Baz>)`).

Start by extracting the non generic part which will serve as base entity (removed non EF Core annotations for clarity):

```cs
// Base class (code/data reuse only, not an entity)
public abstract class DomainEntity<TId>
{
    public TId Id { get; set; }
}

// Base entity
public abstract class VeganItem : DomainEntity<int>
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int IsNotVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public int IsVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public int RatingsCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<Option> Tags { get; set; }

}

// Base class (code/data reuse only, not an entity)
public abstract class VeganItem<TVeganItemEstablishment> : VeganItem
{
    public virtual ICollection<TVeganItemEstablishment> VeganItemEstablishments { get; set; }
}

// Derived entity
public class GroceryItem : VeganItem<GroceryItemEstablishment>
{
}

// Derived entity
public class MenuItem : VeganItem<MenuItemEstablishment>
{
}
```

Then (optionally) add `DbSet` for it

```cs
public DbSet<VeganItem> VeganItems { get; set; }
```

Finally (mandatory) move the fluent configuration of the base entity members to its own block, and keep in derived only the configuration of the specific members of the derive type:

```cs
// Configure base entity
modelBuilder.Entity<VeganItem>(vi =>
{
    vi.HasIndex(e => new { e.CompanyName, e.Name }).IsUnique();
    vi.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
    vi.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
    vi.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    vi.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
    vi.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
    vi.Property(e => e.Tags)
        .HasConversion(
            v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
            v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Option>>(v, null),
            new ValueComparer<IList<Option>>(
                (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
                c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
                c => (IList<Option>)c.ToList()));
});

// Configure derived entities
modelBuilder.Entity<GroceryItem>(gi =>
{
});

modelBuilder.Entity<MenuItem>(mi =>
{
});
```